# Magento order status change events

Tags: php, magento

I want to change via web service a remote inventory, I know that via Event Observer Method can triger my code, but I don't know which event is useful to complete my task, like on_order_complete, is there an updated list of events or more documentation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to dispatch an event when the state of an order changes to any status or state, then you'll need to insert your own event listener. This isn't as difficult as it sounds.

Simply override the *`_setStatus`* function in *`Mage_Sales_Model_Order`* like so...

```
/**
 * Order model
 *
 * @category    WMG
 * @package     WMG_Sales
 * @author      Lee Bolding <lee.bolding@wmg.com>
 *
 *  Supported events:
 *  sales_order_status_before
 *  sales_order_status_after
 *
 * NOTE: Unfortunately, we can't override setState() as the protected _setState()
 * function is used by the registerCancellation() and _checkState() functions
 *  
 */
class WMG_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
    /**
     * Order state protected setter.
     * By default allows to set any state. Can also update status to default or specified value
     * Сomplete and closed states are encapsulated intentionally, see the _checkState()
     *
     * @param string $state
     * @param string|bool $status
     * @param string $comment
     * @param bool $isCustomerNotified
     * @param $shouldProtectState
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    protected function _setState($state, $status = false, $comment = '', $isCustomerNotified = null, $shouldProtectState = false)
    {
        // dispatch an event before we attempt to do anything
        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_status_before', array('order' => $this, 'state' => $state, 'status' => $status, 'comment' => $comment, 'isCustomerNotified' => $isCustomerNotified, 'shouldProtectState' => $shouldProtectState));

        // attempt to set the specified state
        if ($shouldProtectState) {
            if ($this->isStateProtected($state)) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('The Order State "%s" must not be set manually.', $state));
            }
        }
        $this->setData('state', $state);

        // add status history
        if ($status) {
            if ($status === true) {
                $status = $this->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($state);
            }
            $this->setStatus($status);
            $history = $this->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, false); // no sense to set $status again
            $history->setIsCustomerNotified($isCustomerNotified); // for backwards compatibility
        }

        // dispatch an event after status has changed
        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_status_after', array('order' => $this, 'state' => $state, 'status' => $status, 'comment' => $comment, 'isCustomerNotified' => $isCustomerNotified, 'shouldProtectState' => $shouldProtectState));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

You can now subscribe observers to the newly created `sales_order_status_before` and `sales_order_status_after` events

Answer (score 2):

i guess a bit better solution is to watch out for changes, without using a rewrite:

http://www.cartware.de/blog/detail/article/kein-magento-event-fuer-statusaenderung/

By reading the code you may get the clue even its writte in german language...

Answer (score 1):

I did a [blog post](http://masteringmagento.com/2010/06/events-list-in-magento-community-1-4/) about this (which contains the full event list for Magento CE 1.4) a few weeks ago.

The events that may interest you for an order placement is `sales_order_place_after`, which gets called after the order is placed (seriously!).

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe, excellent post but I have some questions:
This sales_order_place_after fires when the administrator complete the order? or is just when the user finish the cekout process?
I need to change when the administrator completes the order after shipping notification to the user

Comment: The sales_order_place_after event fires when an order is added to the system. If you're looking for a single event when the order is moved to a 'completed' state, there is no specific event for that. You should be able to use sales_order_save_after instead and check the status of the order.

Comment: Dead link :( ... try http://web.archive.org/web/20101114192042/http://masteringmagento.com/2010/06/events-list-in-magento-community-1-4/

Answer (score 0):

Use grep to find the list of events, it must be something like

```
grep -rn -A2 --include="*.php" dispatchEvent /var/www/magento/
```

or something like that...

Comment: This will show the default core events.. he need to implements his own event, as it not provided by magento's core.