# Can't override Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Tags: magento

I have such section in config.xml

```
<global>        
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order>Apptha_Reservation_Model_Order</order>                   
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
```

In addition, I have download Alan Strom config viewer from here http://alanstorm.com/magento_config
but when I check myhost.com/?showConfig=true, I don't see my new rewrite rule.

Comment: I can't rewite it this way. Thefore just create local/Mage/Sale/Model/Order.php 
But anyway I am interested why 1st way doesnt work for me.

Comment: A more important question is to ask why you are rewriting this class. There is an event architecture which can be hooked to implement custom functionality, and this is generally preferred over class rewrites. It can be a matter of style though.

Comment: I need just override protected function _setState to in insert two events in it 'sales_order_status_before' and 'sales_order_status_after'. And then hook this event in function which add additional info to db when order status changed to complete.

Comment: Might not work for your application, but this could *potentially* be done by observing the already existing `sales_order_save_before` and `sales_order_save_after` events and using the `Varien_Object` inherited [`hasDataChangedFor()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/lib/Varien/Object.php#L782) method.

Comment: I belive sales_order_place_before and sales_order_place_after run on user checkout. But I need know when order status is changed to "complete" to make some actions. Thefore I create own events into _setState.

Comment: Originally I have read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046530/magento-order-status-change-events before begin to add own events

Comment: `$order->hasDataChangedFor('state');`

Comment: thanks you, I will try to rewrite my code to use core events with this methode.

Comment: Is your Order.php file located at `app/code/local/apptha/reservation/model`?  What does your directory structure look like for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities when module configuration is not being merged into Magento's configuration DOM:

1. Configuration is being cached. Clear it by flushing all in **System > Cache Management**
2. Your module's *config.xml* is not being parsed due to incorrect module declaration or incorrect path.
3. `global/disable_local_modules` is set to `1` or `true` - in general, see `app/etc/local.xml`, but the only way to know for sure is to inspect the full DOM.

In the case of (2), troubleshooting should occur only after config cache has been cleared. Then, check each of the conditions for your module's *config.xml* file to be parsed into the configuration DOM:

1. Correct module declaration: an file with a name ending in ".xml" containing valid XML syntax present in *app/etc/* or in *app/etc/modules/* (by convention, it's the latter).
2. The module contains structure as follows (currently SO is not displaying these correctly; [see gist instead](https://gist.github.com/3884487)):

   true 
                local
3. Based on the above configuration, the config file *must* be located at *app/code/local/Module/Path/etc/config.xml* and must contain valid XML syntax in order to be parsed.

Provided that module declaration and file paths are correct, the likely culprit is invalid syntax. This can be determined by setting the developer mode flag and ensuring that PHP is displaying errors (see *index.php*).