# How to get completion date of an order in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm manually building up a report in Magento using collections and I'm trying to make this use the order completion date instead of the order created date.

My current code is:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', array('eq' => 2));
```

I've found the following question where the user suggest manually logging all of the status changes for each order manually.

[Finding out when an order status has been set to completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213326/finding-out-when-an-order-status-has-been-set-to-completed)

As I'm wanting to use this in a collection I don't believe this is a suitable way, also I somewhat expect this sort of information to be accessible in Magento.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrieve a collection of the order-status-history updates:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at', 'parent_id')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq'=>'complete'))
    ->load();
```

After which you can iterate the $collection and extract the parent_id and the created_at for the information you want.