# Customer Information update at the time of order is completed

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I want to update customer information at the time of order completion,
I have search many things but i have not founs any event which work at the time of order marked as completed.
Now i am used magento 1.6.1.0.

please suggest me and provide some solution of this problem. so i update customer information at the time of order completion.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046530/magento-order-status-change-events

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you searched? couple of magento addon links. if they are not what you are looking for then you need to hire a developer.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/edit-order-address-faster.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/update-order-addresses.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/integrations.html

Comment: I don't want any module for customer address update, i want to magento event which work on at the time of order completion.

Comment: [magento event wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events)