# Magento order status change event

Tags: php, magento

I am writing a Magento extension to export orders.
I only want to export the orders when the orders are marked as processing or completed.

What is the best way to do this? Is there an event for when the order status' changes? Or is there an event for everytime an order is saved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event "for everytime an order is saved" is `sales_order_place_after`

I'm not sure that there are events on the order status' changes, however [this SO topic might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046530/magento-order-status-change-events)

Comment: Thanks for that. I think you are correct- I don't think there is anything about an order status change. I ended up hooking into the event for when an invoice is generated. Thanks!